# usb not writable or readable

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

Since I have upgraded my mobile to marshmallow I am not able to see the files in  my san disk 128 gb pendrive on either MX player or file manager which I have downloaded from play store. I was able to do so earlier. However when I connect my pendrive a notification pops up in my notification bar saying sandisk usb drive. But the problem is I cannot see these files in MX player or file manager. Niether can I delete any files from san disk usb drive. Files are only readable there and I can only copy them. They can't be deleted from there. Also when I go in the menu options of the drive my options for moving pictures and video are frozen. I don't know how to access them. They are not clickable. Please help me to allow my pendrive to be readable and writable in mx player and file manager

Answer (score -1):

If your device is rooted [Stickmount](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.stickmount) should fix the problem

Comment: Have you understood the problem clearly? OP doesn't have an issue with mounting the USB drive. Files are readable and can be copied but can't be modified. Some apps are unable to read anything. Tell us how that app you linked tackles this issue and solves it.

Comment: Android itself doesn't always work with the usb devices correctly while specific apps do, what stickmount does is mount the device as a folder of internal storage

Comment: I don't know how the issue used to get tackled by MX player and file manager when my moto g3 was having android lollipop..but since I have updated it to marshmallow I can't see those files in those apps. My device is also not rooted so are there any other options for me.

Comment: I had a similar issue and stickmount fixed it, but since your device isn't rooted i don't have any other suggestions